# Owl Carousel fade effect doesn't work when you drag or swipe

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

The fade effect works properly when you click on the dots or arrows. But when you swipe or drag, it's sliding. How can I make fade effect for dragging too?

You can see an exaple on the Owl Carousel demo: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html - when you click dots - it's fading, but when you drag - it's sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Only by css, for ex.:

```
.owl-item {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
}
.owl-item.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But visually, swiping/sliding will occur, but the new slide will appear with the effect.
You can also disable drag by options:

```
mouseDrag: false,
touchDrag: false,
```